# Can Linq retrieve rows from datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I am using WPF datagrid. Can I retrieve rows from datagrid using Linq.

Something like :

```
List<People> people = from products in datagrid1 select products.ToList<People>();
```

I think no right? It will be great if Linq support datagrid.

Thank you.

Comment: What have putted in the datagrid1.DataSource property?

Comment: `.ToList<People>()` is obviosly unneccessary.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?? You can bind the datagrid to a collection and query the collection directly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem you're running into is that `ItemsSource` is weakly typed as just `IEnumerable` - whereas most of LINQ to Objects works on `IEnumerable<T>`. You can use the `Cast<T>()` method to create a sequence which will cast each item where necessary. Try this:

```
List<People> people = datagrid1.ItemsSource.Cast<People>().ToList();
```

Note that whenever you see a que ry expression of the form `from x in source select x` you should consider just using `source` - query expressions shouldn't be used blindly; work out what each one means, and then determine whether it's the most appropriate way of expressing what you need.

If you *actually* want a bigger query, you may not want to go via a `List<People>` at all. For example:

```
// Note the explicit typing of the range variable, which corresponds to a Cast
// call in the query translation.
var query = from People person in datagrid1.ItemsSource
            where person.Age > 50
            select person.Name;
```

(Consider changing your `People` type to `Person` by the way, unless it really does represent a collection of people - in which case you should probably give it a name which reflects what the collection really means.)

Comment: @KevFixx: Well we can't possibly know that - we have no idea how you've populated your data grid to start with...

Comment: This is how I insert into the datagrid : this.dgProductList.Items.Add(new { Name=people.Name, Price=people.Price});

Comment: @KevFixx If you are adding items like that then you should query Items property, not ItemsSource.

Comment: using var query = from People person in datagrid1.Items 
            where person.Age > 50 
            select person.Name; not working

Comment: "not working" is *never* enough information about what's going wrong. It sounds like there are multiple potential problems here - for one thing, if your data is an anonymous type, how would you expect to be able to cast it to `People`?

Answer (score 4):

you should be able to query the `ItemSource` property of the datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<People> people = (from product in datagrid1.ItemsSource
                       select product).ToList<People>();
```